# Forcing nodes to stick together within bubble force layout

Tags: d3.js, visualization, force-layout

I have created a force layout that I'm very happy with. The nodes cluster nicely by their group (in the below case Country).

[Working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Iwc.jpg)

As I view them grouped by the other data variables they move to their new centers as expected.

[Recentered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMFRJ.jpg)

What isn't happening, which I'd like, is that at their new center the nodes cluster to their own type as also, like a secondary level of attraction.

i.e. in the above image I'd like that at each "age" center, the nodes for each country are attracted to each other as well rather than being spread across the age area.

Is this possible? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

TIA,

Martin